# Recyclerview in a fargment inside a view pager, does not scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my activity there is a toolbar, a tablayout and a viewpager.
Inside the viewpager there are 3 fragments and each of them has a recyclerview inside.

**activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/big_stone">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:theme="@style/WallSearchView"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:queryBackground="@null"
                app:queryHint="@string/msg_searchView_hint_message"
                app:searchIcon="@null" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearanceSmallTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cloud_burst"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/vermilion"
            app:tabMode="auto"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/silver" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_layout_list.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/big_stone"
    tools:context=".fragments.MyListsFragment">

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see in the gif the recyclerview does not scroll, what can I improve in the design to avoid this?

[image: RecyclerView]

I don't understand if the problem is the recyclerView or the fragment because it gives me the impression that the recyclerView is not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
android: nestedScrollingEnabled = "true"
```

you need to add. It allows the scroll operation to be performed inside.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried in the recyclerView and in the viewPager

Comment: ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);